# How do you run java files using .bat files without editing PATH

Tags: java, batch-file

This question has been asked many times, but I can't find an answer that fixes my situation.

---

...jdk1.8.0_20\bin
 - textEditor *[folder]*
 - javac.exe
 - java.exe
 - TextEditor.bat

---

...jdk1.8.0_20\bin\textEditor
 - TextEditor.class
 - TextEditor.java

---

I'm working on a computer where I don't want to change the PATH file.
My TextEditor.bat file contains this

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 textEditor\TextEditor.java
java textEditor\TextEditor
```

Everytime I run this, it compiles fine, but won't run:

> Error: Could not find or load main class textEditor\TextEditor

Comment: try to state absolute paths...

Comment: Is it possibly outputting the compiled code to a different place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the package.

If this is your file :

```
public class foo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("foo");    
   }
}
```

and this file is in the pkg directory, I can do this:

```
javac pkg/foo.java
```

but this will not work:

```
java pkg/foo
```

produces

```
Error: Could not find or load main class pkg.foo
```

but this would.

```
java -cp pkg foo
```

If I add a package statement at the beginning like :

```
package pkg;
public class foo {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println("foo");    
   }
}
```

I can still compile like this:

```
javac pkg/foo.java
```

and now run like this:

```
java pkg/foo
```

The rule is that the classpath needs to be at the top of your package directories.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like this

```
java -cp . textEdtor\TextEditor
```

-cp specifies the classpath which does not automatically include .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys! I had developed the program on another computer using eclipse and had the package in the TextEditor.java file as `package main;`, but I had it in a folder called TextEditor so that I could easily distinguish it in my portable JDK I had on my flashdrive.

**TLDR;** *The folder the .java class resides in must have the same name as the* `package whatever;`.